# Add a "default view" Developer Story preference

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

As covered many times in discussions about the Developer Story, part of the idea behind having a "story" view and a "traditional" view (I'll come back to the information design problem of those not being a pair) is different formats will work for different people, different work histories, etc. But right now the Developer Story's choice of views doesn't really give users control of which view people see.

Yes `http://stackoverflow.com/cv/storyslug` is still accessible, and once you've navigated to a users Developer Story tab you can click "Traditional view" to see the CV layout. But clicking on the "Developer Story" tab by default displays the "Story view." I expect that anyone who decides to navigate to an Stack Overflow user's career history by clicking through from their profile page will *only* ever look at the "Story view".

(This is where the false pair of "story"/"traditional" has an extra impact: my intuition is that to anyone unfamiliar with the history of CV/Careers/Developer story will read "story view" as "the content that belongs in this section" and "traditional view" as "some old legacy thing." Why would anyone click "legacy version?")

A "default view" in the Developer Story Preferences, which would determine whether `http://stackoverflow.com/users/story/userid` displays `...?view=Timeline` or `...?view=Cv`, would let the user give more weight to one or the other of the Story views. That would help Developer Story meet the expressed goal of supporting the differing needs of different career histories.

**Edit:** This is more radical, because it would introduce some variation into the user profiles, but to truly give users control we would need to allow them to hide one of the "view" links. Not sure if that's a good idea or not, but I *do* think that if we don't support it the mods will need to revisit the "you don't have to use the Story if you don't want it" idea.

Comment: Soo... rename traditional view to View curriculum vitae not an option?

Comment: I definitely think renaming "traditional" to something meaningful would also be a good move

Answer (score -5):

Thanks for the feedback. We want the Story view to be the default view as we believe it’s a better representation of a developer's ability. This is especially true for developers that don’t have formal work or educational experience and who would normally have a bland CV.

We've kept the traditional view as this is the default view we share with employers (if your settings allow). We want to make sure users can see how they’ll be viewed by employers. In time we may prioritise the story view for employers too and remove the traditional view altogether. We’d still retain the traditional view public links and PDF export if this happens.

At this time, we’re not going to add a default view option, but if the need arises, then we will revisit the possibility down the road.

Comment: I'm having trouble tracking down useful specific quotes, but I feel like I've seen other mods (Shog, I would guess) saying things along the lines of "the reason to continue supporting the old layout is we know it will be better for some people." I don't expect to change your mind —your hinting at a half-planned retirement of the old view makes me think the timeline is roughly in place— but it's hard for me to see any value in not letting the user choose. There's the factor of individuals' work histories, as well as the factor of which view is more suitable for a given job. …

Comment: … In my case, after extensive searching I found that SO's CV was easily the best available for my needs. A good developer CV seems a hot commodity, and SO had the market cornered. The Developer Story is interesting, and will be great for some people, and I'm sure comes with enhanced searching powers for employers. But you had a great product, and rather than adding a second complementary product you're saying you're trading one that world for some for another that works for some. I see myself cloning the CV layout on a personal site so as to not have to deal with employers seeing the Story

Comment: *one that works for some people for another that works for some people